# Mongoose select query between two time range for same day or time crosses midnight according to coordinate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am working on a food delivery project, and use mongoDB.
I want to query between two time ranges or same day or time crosses midnight according to coordinate.

This is the Schema for restaurants time and coordinates:

```
location: { type: { type: String }, coordinates: [Number] },
rest_timing:[{
        day:{type: String},
        open_time:{type: String},
        close_time:{type: String}
    }],
```

I need ideas how can i solve, because i am newto mongo.

Comment: Please explain it more with sample data and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Aabid i have not tried anything, i am completely new to node js.

Comment: Can you please tell me the format of open_time or close time?

Comment: i am storing time in 24 hr format like this

Comment: [{day: '1',
open_time:'10:32', 
close_time: '23:00'
},
{
day: '2',
open_time:'20:00', 
close_time: '06:00'
}]

Comment: @ShivamPandey for day 1(monday) time is 10:32am - 11pm same day  and for day 2 (Tuesday) time is 8pm - 6am next day